# Hive Track changes in a column

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, impala

Hi I have been trying to monitor divergence from an original value in a column in hive.  For Example:

```
column 1  tracking_column
6          0
6          0
6          0
5          -1
6          0
6          0
7          1
8          2
```

I have been using the lag function however this only seems to allow me to track a change from one row to the next and does not keep a running count.  So when the number goes up from 6 to 7 and then to 8.  lag or lead I dont think will work in this case.

Any tips appreciated.  Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `first_value()`:

```
select col1, (first_value(col1) over (order by ?) - col1) as diff
from t;
```

The `?` is a placeholder for the column that specifies the ordering of the table.

You could also use `cross join`:

```
select t.col1, (t.col1 - t1.col1) as diff
from t cross join
     (select t.*
      from t
      order by ?
      limit 1
     ) t1;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that is exactly what I was trying to do.